Which city has the highest number of actively used currencies?
I read that in Poipet, Cambodia, most merchants including street sellers and tuk tuk drivers accept 3 currencies, namely KHR
(Cambodian Riel), THB (Thai Baht) and USD (United States Dollar). This makes me wonder: which city has the highest number of actively used currencies?
By "actively used currency", I mean a currency that is accepted by the majority of merchants.

I'm not sure this is answerable. I'm not aware of any country that has more than two legal currencies, and while many border towns accept multiple currencies, the rates are rarely in your favor.

@lambshaanxy thanks, do you think it may not be answerable?

Do the variations of the Pound Sterling (Bank of England, Scottish, Northern Irish, Manx, Guernsey and Jersey pounds) count? If so Jersey and Guernsey probably have the record as they accept all 6 (the reverse is not true in most of the UK).

Particular businesses in tourist destinations will often accept a variety of tourist currencies, but that doesn't mean the majority of merchants, particularly smaller merchants not primarily catering to tourists, will accept them. And if you go to a tourist city, whether Dublin or Bangkok, there will be a lot of businesses catering to locals with little or no tourist traffic and little or no inclination to accept more than the most common currency. So how are you going to calculate this?

USD would surely not be an official currency. If some foreign coin collector starts selling coffee and accepts any currency around the world as payment, does that mean that the town they are living in now has 200+ accepted currencies?

@jcaron Thanks, that would be a good answer. You are welcome to post your comment as an answer.

@StuartF then that doesn't count. By "actively used currency", I mean a currency that is accepted by the majority of merchants. For example in Bangkok, the majority of merchants will only accept THB

@Lundin then that doesn't count. By "actively used currency", I mean a currency that is accepted by the majority of merchants

An interesting but tricky question.  At one extreme of every business or trader accepting multiple currencies, the answer is probably none.  At the other extreme of a few businesses accepting multiple currencies, the answer is probably very large.

I have experienced the opposite: surprisingly few currencies.  This is an old story.  Colombo airport in Sri Lanka would only accept US Dollars and not Sri Lankan Rupees.  Of course, the prices were much higher.  It was frustrating to be in Sri Lanka with Sri Lankan money and not be able to buy a Sri Lankan newspaper.  The expectation that all foreigners would have dollars was also irritating.

In Cuba you can pay a lot of merchants with Cuban Pesos, USD and Euros.

@Hilmar thanks, sounds like a good answer

Let me introduce you to the existance of cities Tiraspol and Bendery in unrecognized state of Transnistrian Moldavian Republic.
I'm not sure about the current situation, but in the 00s, one would expect active use of Moldavian Leu MDL, Russian Rouble RUB, Ukrainian Hryvna UAH, Euro EUR, US Dollar USD, Romanian Leu RON, as well as local ПМР currency Transnistrian Rouble with its notable plastic polygonal coins.

Apparently, the place with the highest number of accepted currencies is Hong Kong. In addition to the official HKD, the following currencies are also commonly accepted: CNY, EUR, GBP, USD, JPY.
Source

Only some hotels and department stores will accept all those currencies, like about anywhere else in the world. You won’t pay anything in any of those currencies in most places in HK. They’re definitely not commonly accepted.

If you hop on the ferry to Macau, they deal with all those currencies plus the Macanese pataca (MOP) as well.  Although in practice only HKD/MOP acceptance is universal, maybe CNY in a pinch.

@jcaron not even CNY and USD?

@Johnnyjanko CNY may be accepted more widely than anything else (never tried), but I don't think USD would be accepted in any regular store or restaurant.
